# Understanding strspn(const char *s, const char *accept) function

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a program that reads a file line by line to separate word and translation. The code below works. However I am unable to understand how `/* separate word and translation */` part of the `load_dictionary` function actually works. [image: I ran it through **gdb**].

**Things unclear**:

- output of `p line`
- output of `p word` after `word = line + strspn(line, DELIMS)`. Isn't `strspn` supposed to read till `DELIMS` \t and print - *ants\t*.

**FILE:** dict.txt

```
WORD    TRANSLATION

ants    anttt
anti    eti
ante    soggy
anda    eggs
```

Function: **main**

```
 /* maximum number of characters for word to search */
 #define WORD_MAX 256

 /* maximum number of characters in line */
 #ifndef LINE_MAX
 #define LINE_MAX 2048
 #endif

 int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
        char word[WORD_MAX], * translation;
        int len;

        if (argc <= 1)
            return 0; /* no dictionary specified */

        /* load dictionary */
        load_dictionary(argv[1]);
        return 0;
  }
```

Function: **load_dictionary**:- *read dictionary file*

```
/* delimiter for dictionary */
#define DELIMS "\t"

unsigned void load_dictionary(const char * filename) {
        FILE * pfile;
        char line[LINE_MAX], * word, * translation;

        /* ensure file can be opened */
        if ( !(pfile = fopen(filename,"r")) )
            return icount;

        /* read lines */
        while ( (fgets(line, LINE_MAX, pfile)) ) {
            /* strip trailing newline */
            int len = strlen(line);
            if (len > 0 && line[len-1] == '\n') {
              line[len-1] = '\0';
              --len;
            }

            /* separate word and translation */
            word = line + strspn(line, DELIMS);

            if ( !word[0] )
                continue; /* no word in line */
            translation = word + strcspn(word, DELIMS);
            *translation++ = '\0';
            translation += strspn(translation, DELIMS);
        }
 }
```

Comment: [POSIX `strspn()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html): "strspn - get length of a substring"

Comment: Please do not send screenshots of text terminals.

Comment: Please copy/paste the text.  As it is, the image is unreadable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strspn` will give the number of initial chars that are present in `DELIM`

`strcspn` will give the number of initial chars that are **not** present in `DELIM`

(see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html)

So the idea of the code is to use simple pointer arithmetic to make the `word` and `translation` pointers to point at first word in the input and second word in the input. Further, the code adds a NUL termination after the first word so that it looks like two strings.

Example:

```
line: \t\t\t\tC++\0\t\t\tA programming language
              ^   ^      ^
              |   |      |
              |   |      translation points here
              |   |      
              |   NUL added here
              |  
              word points here
```

So printing `word` and `translation` will give:

```
C++
A programming language
```

The code with additional comments:

```
        word = line + strspn(line, DELIMS);  // Skip tabs, i.e. 
                                             // make word point to the
                                             // first character which is
                                             // not a tab (aka \t)

        if ( !word[0] )
            continue; /* no word in line */

        translation = word + strcspn(word, DELIMS); // Make translation point to the
                                                    // first character after word 
                                                    // which is a tab (aka \t), i.e. it 
                                                    // points to the character just after
                                                    // the first word in line



        *translation++ = '\0';               // Add the NUL termination and
                                             // increment translation

        translation += strspn(translation, DELIMS);   // Skip tabs, i.e. 
                                                      // make translation point to the
                                                      // second word in line which is
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to post more code to make clear what is happening, but from what you have posted I suggest that you...

- have a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strcspn-in-c/ the aim is to break up the line into individual words - it seems that `\t` is expected between words - from the file there is a `\t` between the word and translation.
  So `strcspn` returns the number of characters to the next `\t` character and then the pointers are moved on by that number of characters - and it looks like the `\t` character between word and translation are replace by a `\0` character.

The file is read in line by line to the array `char line[...`. So pointer `line` points to the beginning of the array `line[...`.